# Typeclass instance for function

Tags: haskell

I'm working on the homework problems for [CIS 194](http://www.seas.upenn.edu/~cis194/lectures.html).
I am stuck at [Homework 5](http://www.seas.upenn.edu/~cis194/hw/05-type-classes.pdf), Question 6.

The typeclass `Expr` is used to represent an expression and the typeclass `HasVars` for any expression containing variables.
The Question asks to implement an instance of `Expr` for `M.Map String Integer -> Maybe Integer`, where `M` is `Data.Map`.

```
class Expr a where 
  add :: a -> a -> a
  mul :: a -> a -> a
  lit :: Integer -> a
```

Here's the code for instance of `Expr` for `Integer`.

```
instance Expr Integer where
  add m n = m + n
  mul m n = m * n
  lit m = m
```

and for the `HasVars` instance of the function,

```
instance HasVars (M.Map String Integer -> Maybe Integer) where
   var s  = M.lookup s
```

I am confused as how to create instance of `Expr` for the function type. 
How would one go about either pattern matching or extracting values from a function ? 
The type is `a-> a -> a`, so I don't have a `Map` to extract the values and `var` from `ShowVars` is used to convert a `String` into the said function.

I'm not putting up solutions to the other parts of the question because it may contain spoilers.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, first write out the signatures so it's clear what stuff is supposed to be. To make it more readable,

```
type MS2I = M.Map String Integer
type Integer' = Maybe Integer
```

then

```
add :: (MS2I -> Integer') -> (MS2I -> Integer') -> (MS2I -> Integer')
```

So you can start with

```
add m n = o
 where m, n, o :: MS2I -> Integer'
```

So `o` is a function taking a map... you can define that:

```
add m n = o
 where o ms2i = ...
```

Now at that point you have a map. You can feed that to the arguments:

```
add m n = o
 where o ms2i = let i1 = m ms2i
                    i2 = n ms2i
                    i1, i2 :: Integer'
                in ...?
```

The rest should be obvious, you just need to combine two `Maybe Integer` to a new one. (Best use `Applicative`.)

For fun and reference, here's a super-condensed version:

```
import Control.Arrow
instance Expr (Kleisli Maybe MS2I Integer) where
  add m n = arr (uncurry(+)) . (m&&&n)
```

Comment: Perhaps too advanced at this stage, but if you're using `Applicative` to combine the `Maybe`s, you can use it for the function part as well. `add = liftA2 $ liftA2 (+)`.

Comment: Thanks that made sense. However the `lit :: Integer -> a` is still throwing me of. I need to create the function using only an integer. So I need to create a map or add to one ?

Comment: @dare_take `lit` probably makes an expression that's meant to be constant, so make it take a map argument but ignore it.